# Change LaTeX caption language

Tags: latex, caption

How could I change the default language so that I get something else instead of "Table" or "Figure" before my captions?

Comment: Do you want to change the language i.e English->Spanish or do you just want to specify what the caption says?

Answer (score 11):

You can redefine `\figurename` and `\tablename` by using `\renewcommand`. For example, you can do this for Swedish:

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figur}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabell}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can change your document's language using `babel` package. The captions will be updated automatically.

As a bonus, you'll get the correct hyphenation for the chosen language.

Comment: All languages aren't available. I tried Swedish (both by specifying `svenska` and `swedish`), but it said it wasn't available. French worked though, by using `francais`.

Comment: @DonaldDuck: Perhaps you are using an outdated babel? [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75006/1640) reports that Swedish is available.

Comment: @​Vlad I'm sure it's not outdated, I just installed it.

Comment: @DonaldDuck: If you are using MikTeX, maybe you didn't install all the needed languages?

Answer (score 5):

You can also redefine `\tablename` and `\figurename`.