# latex caption language (2)

Tags: latex, caption

Referring to this question ([Change LaTeX caption language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709562/latex-caption-language)), I got the same problem and it does not get solved by the use of the correct language package.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,inner=6cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}
\geometry{twoside}

\usepackage{lmodern}%font
\usepackage[francais]{babel}%language corrector and punctuation rules
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage[font=small]{caption}%titres des figures
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Calendrier approximatif du processus législatif.}
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.65\textwidth}
                    p{0.1\textwidth}
                }
Analyse du problème, fixation des objectifs et définition des moyens d'action possibles & 1 an\\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

What do I do wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The standard tag for a table defined in `frenchb.ldf` is the word “Table”.

If you want it to become “Tableau”, for instance, you have to tell `babel` to.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%encoding
\usepackage[francais]{babel}%language corrector and punctuation rules

\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,inner=6cm,outer=2cm]{geometry}
\geometry{twoside}

\usepackage{lmodern}%font

\usepackage[font=small]{caption}%titres des figures
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand\frenchtablename{{\FBfigtabshape Tableau}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Calendrier approximatif du processus législatif.}
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.65\textwidth}
                    p{0.1\textwidth}
                }
Analyse du problème, fixation des objectifs et définition des moyens d'action possibles & 1 an\\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I have also changed the package loading order to a better one. Note that you don't need to pass the `pdftex` option to `graphicx` (unless you have a ***very*** old TeX distribution).

[image]